# Getting 403 error from Amazon S3/CloudFront only with certain IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

We are serving files to our site from an S3 over Cloudfront. This has been working fine for a long time and been untouched. Today I noticed that all the files we are trying to serve from our private bucket were not working anymore, they were returing 403 errors, with error code SignatureDoesNotMatch.

I dove into this and realized when I disconnect from the internet I was using everything seems fine. When I used my phone using data everything loaded ok, I also got other people on other wifi connections to try and they did not report any issues, everything working ok. 
On my machine I tried using different browsers, but as long as I was connected to my own internet connection I was getting this error. Also it does not appear to be related to my machine, since its worked on my phone as long as I was not connected to my wifi. As soon as I did, it no longer worked.

I tested our dev environment also, which uses a different s3 bucket and different cloudfront (but configured the same way, and nothing has been changed for both dev and live site for months) and that was working totally fine on my internet also.

That being said, even though im getting SignatureDoesNotMatch as the error code, I cannot imagine that being the actual issue, as it seems to depend on the connection Im coming from.

Does anyone have a clue about what I can look for here to try to solve this? Is it possible that there is some mechanism blocking me on Amazons end?

**UPDATE:**
Live site now getting blocked from my phone also. Dev site still working on both connections. I have attempt to stream a lot, is it possible AWS blocks IPs that seem to be trying to stream a lot? I really have no idea whats going on anymore.

This is a copy of the full error when getting it (again this intermittent and sometimes youll get this error, but you can refresh the page with a different internet connection and it will load the file fine): [screenshot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCSo3.png)

Comment: Wonder if your ISP is injecting something (tracking-related?) into the requests that is causing this.

Comment: Im using my university's student internet so I dont have much control over it, but it was working fine until today. Its really only getting from that bucket on this internet connection. Other buckets (even private) work ok. Meaning for my dev site Im using the same code to generate the signed URL. for the bucket I use for my dev site it works fine. it just stopped working for the live site this morning

Comment: The error response should contain more than the error code SignatureDoesNotMatch. Capture and print the full error response to see if has additional text that helps.